# how does this assignment work in c#?

Tags: c#

My question is that how does this assignment happen in c#? I mean, how does it calculate the answer 1 (with 257), and how does it calculate 0(with 256)?

the code is:

```
int intnumber=257;
byte bytenumber=(byte)intnumber;//the out put of this code is 1

int intnumber=256;
byte bytenumber=(byte)intnumber;//the out put of this code is 0
```

My question is what happen,that the output in first code is:1 and in second one is:0

Comment: please read my question exactly then give me a negative vote!!! thanks

Comment: The first is *not* required to set `bytenumber` to `1`, although it may. If compiling with overflow checks enabled, it will not set `bytenumber` to anything, it will throw an exception. Similarly for the second.

Comment: @Hava: Okay, I've done that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `byte` data type contains a number between 0 to 255. When converting an `int` to `byte`, it calculates the number modulo 256.

```
byte = int % 256
```

Comment: This is the net effect, but not how it is calculated.

Comment: @lukegravitt The C++ standard defines the equivalent conversion as described in this answer, but pretty much no one will object to saying the high bits get discarded. It's only fitting that when the C# spec says the high bits get discarded, it's explained as a modulo operation. It's the same thing anyway :)

Comment: Indeed. He didn't ask about the MSBs, he just wanted to know how it works, and this is the simplest of answers.

Comment: @EZSlaver - how well does this simplest answer extend to the casting of negative ints to byte?

Comment: Well, the same way casting any signed value to an unsigned value. You could say that what happens is `int -> uint -> byte`. This is still simpler than thinking in bits. This is a very-high-level language, and even though I know assembly and how operations work bitwise, that's supposed to be theoratically irrelevant in languages such as C# and Java.

Comment: It's not even necessary to add an extra conversion step for that: casting negative ints to a byte is still explainable as a modulo operation. -1 = 255 (mod 256). However, the `%` operator takes the *remainder*, which is a closely related yet for signed values subtly different operation.

Comment: @hvd - my point was that taken simply, people may initially think -1 % 256 = -1, and then require additional explanation for how the cast is computed. Also, using the % operator (a normally expensive operation) to explain the cast may convey to some that casting to byte is computationally expensive (it isn't).

Comment: @hatchet That first part is what I meant: -1 % 256 = -1, not 255, because % takes the remainder. The answer would IMO benefit from not using that operator. The second part I disagree with: in an explanation of *how* it happens, I would agree, but for an explanation of *what* happens, I like wording it in whatever way is easiest for the OP to understand.

Comment: @hvd - the OP did ask "how does it (C#) calculate the answer". Conceptually, I agree that for (byte)int it's modulo 256. But `int % 256` is not how C# calculates the answer.

Comment: @hatchet I think I interpreted the question differently, I don't think the "how" is what the OP wanted to know, and EZSlaver answered that the OP really meant to ask. I can agree though that based on what's actually in the question, this isn't an answer.

Comment: If you ask someone in the street "What day is it today?", and his answer will be "August 7th. 2013", you will not be satisfied, though the answer you want is "Wednesday". On that note, it's better to answer whoever asked the question than to answer the question itself.... And that's what I did.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that in describing the effect of the calculation instead of how it works, you are doing the OP and anyone who hits this question again a disservice. By failing to explain the real process, you are not allowing others who accept your answer the opportunity to correctly reason the behavior. Also as pointed out, your answer doesn't even work for negative numbers.

Comment: It does under 2's Complement. But, nevertheless it's all water under the bridge. I understand your point, and you do mine. There's nothing more to say. Farewell.

Answer (score 10):

A `byte` only occupies one byte in memory. An `int` occupies 4 bytes in memory. Here is the binary representation of some int values you've mentioned:

```
      most significant           least significant
 255: 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
 256: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000
 257: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000001
```

You can also see how this works when casting negative int values to a byte. An int value of -255, when cast to a byte, is 1.

```
-255:  11111111 11111111 11111111 00000001
```

When you cast an int to a byte, only the least significant byte is assigned to the byte value. The three higher significance bytes are ignored.

Answer (score 8):

A single byte only goes up to 255. The code wraps around to 0 for 256 and 1 for 257, etc...

The most significant bits are discarded and you're left with the rest.

Answer (score 2):

255 is the maximum value that can be represented in a single `byte`:

Hex code: `FF`

256 does not fit in 1 byte. It takes 2 bites to represent that:

`01 00`

since you're trying to put that value in a variable of type `byte` (which of course may only contain 1 byte), the second byte is "cropped" away, leaving only:

`00`

Same happens for 257 and actually for any value.

Answer (score 1):

1 is assigned because the arithmetic overflow of byte values (max 255) exceed by 2 unit.

0 is assigned because exceed by 1 unit.